# A problem with override controller

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, module, overrides, controllers

I override **Mage_Newsletter_SubscriberController**, in config.xml i'm defined:

```
<routers>
            <hn_con>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Hn_Con</module>
                    <frontName>con</frontName>
                </args>
            </hn_con>
            <newsletter>
                <args>
                    <module before="Mage_Newsletter_SubscriberController">Hn_Con</module>
                </args>
            </newsletter>
        </routers>
```

it's worked, but Newsletter/Manage not working. Why? I just override **Mage_Newsletter_SubscriberController** not override **Mage_Newsletter_ManageController**. Who can explain to me, please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this piece of xml for re-routing controllers.

```
<newsletter>
    <args>
        <Hn_Con before="Mage_Newsletter">Hn_Con</Hn_Con>
    </args>
</newsletter>
```

Now if you have a controllers in `app/code/{codepool}/Hn/Con/controllers` named the same as a controller in the `Mage/Newsletter/controllers`, your controller will be take into consideration. Any other controller in `Mage/Newsletter/controllers` that does not have a corespondent in your module should work like before.